# Pandas DataFrame convert date string

Tags: python, html, pandas, datetime, dataframe

beginner question. If you run the below:

```
df = pd.read_html('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/veritaseum/historical-data/?start=20180101&end=20180105')
```

df

it creates a table:

```
[           Date   Open*    High     Low  Close**   Volume  Market Cap
 0  Jan 05, 2018  366.43  395.69  356.26   380.11   426543   746285248
 1  Jan 04, 2018  376.58  397.02  353.17   368.46   734384   766956544
 2  Jan 03, 2018  378.55  395.28  352.05   376.05  1000590   770974464
 3  Jan 02, 2018  343.79  393.92  335.60   377.54  2011340   700168512
 4  Jan 01, 2018  338.14  357.18  325.33   343.12   890956   688681984]
```

but when you try creating a DataFrame:

```
data_table = pd.DataFrame(df)

data_table
```

Nothing comes out. Is it due to the Date being a string? How can you overcome it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First need select first value of list of DataFrames returned by `read_html` and then use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), if want `DatetimeIndex` add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/veritaseum/historical-data/?start=20180101&end=20180105'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b %d, %Y')
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df)
             Open*    High     Low  Close**   Volume  Market Cap
Date                                                            
2018-01-05  366.43  395.69  356.26   380.11   426543   746285248
2018-01-04  376.58  397.02  353.17   368.46   734384   766956544
2018-01-03  378.55  395.28  352.05   376.05  1000590   770974464
2018-01-02  343.79  393.92  335.60   377.54  2011340   700168512
2018-01-01  338.14  357.18  325.33   343.12   890956   688681984
```

Or use parameters `parse_dates` and if need `DatetimeIndex` also add `index_col`:

```
df = pd.read_html(url, index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])[0]
print(df)
             Open*    High     Low  Close**   Volume  Market Cap
Date                                                            
2018-01-05  366.43  395.69  356.26   380.11   426543   746285248
2018-01-04  376.58  397.02  353.17   368.46   734384   766956544
2018-01-03  378.55  395.28  352.05   376.05  1000590   770974464
2018-01-02  343.79  393.92  335.60   377.54  2011340   700168512
2018-01-01  338.14  357.18  325.33   343.12   890956   688681984
```